# Unable to update View after checking for permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions

I am using the following code to check for *dangerous* permissions for run-time requests.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



    int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
    String[] PERMISSIONS = {Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS, Manifest.permission.VIBRATE};
    if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
    }
    else
    {
        initSetUp();
    }

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {

    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        initSetUp();
    }
    else {
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,ConstantParams.PERMISSION_GRANT_REQUIRED,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
}

public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && context != null && permissions != null) {
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


public void initSetUp()
{
    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

    drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
    drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);

    // display the first navigation drawer view on app launch
    displayView(0,true);
}
```

However, when I click on *Allow* on the permission request screen, app crashes and I get the following exception:

```
 30242-30242/com.abc.xyz E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.abc.xyz, PID: 30242
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=@android:requestPermissions:, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=android.content.pm.action.REQUEST_PERMISSIONS (has extras) }} to activity {com.abc.xyz/activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4998)
             at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5041)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1500)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1518)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:634)
        at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:613)
        at activity.MainActivity.displayView(MainActivity.java:214)
        at activity.MainActivity.initSetUp(MainActivity.java:105)
        at activity.MainActivity.onRequestPermissionsResult(MainActivity.java:73)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchRequestPermissionsResult(Activity.java:7291)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:7169)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4994)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5041)
```

at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:229)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1875)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is happening while setting up drawer not while checking permission.
I am not much experienced with drawerlayout, but the problem is because of commitLoss.